Why are geometric problems of antiquity like Angle Trisection not considered proof that $P \neq NP$?
It may be my incomplete understanding of the $P$ vs. $NP$ problem, but I was wondering why Angle Trisection is not considered a counterexample for $P = NP$.
It was mathematically proven that only using the allowed operations it is impossible to trisect an arbitrary angle. On the other hand, it is trivial to check if a given angle is a  solution to the problem. So it is a problem that can be easily verified but it was proven that no algorithm can exist to solve it in a finite amount of time (using only the allowed operations).
Why is this not considered proof that $P \neq NP$ ?  Is it because the problem statement considers a different set of allowed operations?

$P$ is not the set of "problems that can be solved using allowed geometric operations", it is the set of "problems that can be solved with polynomial-time algorithms". And in fact you can trisect an angle in polynomial time using a protractor and long division.

The problems have nothing to do with one another.
There are many theorems in mathematics that say "X is impossible using tools Y" - here are some examples.

You can't write the square root of $2$ as a quotient of integers.

You can't trisect an angle using Euclidean straightedge and compass constructions.

You can't prove the parallel postulate using the other Euclidean postulates.

You can't find a general formula for the roots of a fifth degree polynomial using ordinary algebra and the extraction of roots.

You can't prove set theory is consistent using only set theory itself.


We don't know whether every problem whose solution can be quickly verified can also be quickly solved. If someone proves $P \ne NP$ then

You can't guarantee a polynomial time algorithm to solve a problem using a known polynomial time algorithm to check a solution.

